# Why is my size always 1 for a stack of more then 1 element?

Tags: java, stack, size

My task is to implement a MyStack class, that takes a given IStack interface and implements the methods. Everything is working except for the size.
My size is always given the value 1.
Here is my code for the size method.

```
    public int size() {
        int count = 0;
        if(isEmpty() == true) {
            return 0;
        }
        else {
            while(head.getNext() != null) {
                count++;
                return count;
            }
            return count;
        }
    }
```

If I delete the return statement inside the while statement the whole thing isn't working anymore.
So do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Remove `return count;` after `count++;` You never iterate more than once

Comment: i tried but then my code failed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need some variable that you can update to store the current item as you iterate through. It's not enough to call `head.getNext()` repeatedly, because that will always be the 1st element.

```
WhateverItemClass current = head.getNext();
while(current != null) {
    count++;
    current = current.getNext();
}
return count;
```

Answer (score 0):

First of don't compare booleans inside an if-statement, simply use:

```
if(isEmpty())
```

And if the program is not terminating when removing the return statement inside the loop, it seems like `getNext()` is always returning a non-null value...